# Static contextMenu in TreeCell

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

In tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/tree-view.htm a contextMenu is added to the TreeCell to allow item specific context.

Instead of creating a new ContextMenu() for every cell would it be feasible in this case to make the ContextMenu static and create items inside static initializer e.g.

```
private final class TextFieldTreeCellImpl extends TreeCell<String> {
    private static final ContextMenu addMenu = new ContextMenu();
    static {
        MenuItem addMenuItem = new MenuItem("Add Employee");
        addMenu.getItems().add(addMenuItem);
        addMenuItem.setOnAction(new EventHandler() {
            public void handle(Event t) {
                TreeItem newEmployee = 
                    new TreeItem<String>("New Employee");
                        getTreeItem().getChildren().add(newEmployee);
            }
        });
    }
```

Is there any benefit in creating a new ContextMenu instance for every cell?

Comment: sorry bad example - obviously one cannot access instance properties such as treeItem in static context - other than that I guess its technically OK.

Comment: The alternative is to construct the ContextMenu outside and call the "addMenu" setter so effectively each TreeCell uses the same ContextMenu instance which is what my question is about.

Comment: If the context menu doesn't depend on the tree item (which is true for "add" functionality), then this is probably a better approach. Usually, though, you find you want some functionality in there which is dependent on the cell on which the context menu was raised (e.g. "Delete Employee"); then the only sensible way to do it is with a context menu on the cell.

Comment: @James - Hi, my question is whether or not its OK to use the same ContextMenu instance on every cell instance (1-*), rather than new ContextMenu on every cell instance (1-1).

Comment: I understand now - for each cell a menuItem action event handler is created & references *this* cell, and must be linked to the contextMenu object at some point. With only one contextMenu instance we easily end up with multiple items showing in the popup.